# How to use admin account to open visual studio 2012 in window 7?

Tags: wpf, windows, visual-studio-2012

i can not login with window admin account to database by clearly define password and user of window admin in app.config and i can login with SSPI

However i am not using admin account to login and open this solution, so SSPI can not login

How to use admin account to open visual studio 2012 in window 7?

**Update No admin can be selected**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unless I have misunderstood your question. Right click Visual Studio icon -> "Run as administrator"?

Comment: Note that if your Visual Studio icon is on the task bar, you'll need to right click that icon and then right click the Visual Studio icon in the popup window and then select 'Run as administrator'.

Comment: Or hold CTRL + SHIFT then click the icon taskbar icon. SHIFT means launch new instance, CTRL means run as administrator.

Comment: i find admin in menu, where is icon taskbar icon?

Comment: @ControlPoly, if you pin Visual Studio to the task bar, the Visual Studio icon will be on the task bar.

Comment: You have to launch Visual Studio with Administrator privileges then open the solution. You can't just open a solution as an Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

i use administrator cmd to open